# Why is :before pseudoelement rendered before content, not element?

Tags: css

There is an example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<head>
<title>An XHTML 1.0 Strict standard template</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<style>
    DIV#outer {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
    }
    DIV#inner {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: green;
    }
    DIV#inner:before {
        display: inline-block;
        content: '123';
        background-color: red;
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

'#inner:before' pseudoelement is rendered inside '#inner'. To make it be rendered outside, I need to replace selector in last css block with 'DIV#outer:before', so it will be rendered inside '#outer', but before '#inner'. The question is why I'm observing such behaviour? [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp) says that "The :before selector inserts content before the selected element(s)". Before element, but not before content of element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

w3schools is [notoriously inaccurate](http://w3fools.com/) and **not** affiliated with the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/).

From the [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content) (emphasis added):

> Authors specify the style and location of generated content with the
>   :before and :after pseudo-elements. As their names indicate, the
>   :before and :after pseudo-elements specify the location of content
>   before and after an element's document tree **content**.

Comment: Thank you! Google places w3schools on top. Next time will read spec.

Comment: @mixel: The spec is a pretty dry read. The MDN docs are pretty good, and always up to date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference

Answer (score 1):

[W3Schools is wrong often.](http://w3fools.com/) In this case it is wrong. [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3abefore) and it's counterpart [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3aafter) are supposed to be inside the element in question, but before and after anything inside it.

The MDN phrases it this way:

> :before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the element matched. Often used to add cosmetic content to an element, by using the content property. This element is inline by default.