# Why are my :before & :after pseudo elements not rendering in my Styled Components?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, pseudo-element

For some reason I'm having a rendering issue when it comes to implementing `content` in a `:before` or `:after` pseudo element. Given the stripped down component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Container = styled.div`
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
`;

const Foo = styled.p`
  &:before {
    content: '\201C';
    display: block;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 4.25rem;
  }

  &:after {
    content: '\201D';
    display: block;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 2.625rem;
  }

  font-weight: bold;
`;

function Test({ txt }) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Foo>{txt}</Foo>
    </Container>
  );
}

Test.propTypes = {
    txt: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default Test;
```

Nothing gets rendered. Referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49671572/1952287) from [How to render pseudo before content dynamically in styled-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339034/how-to-render-pseudo-before-content-dynamically-in-styled-component) I tried:

```
const Foo = styled.p`
  &:before {
    content: '\201C';
    display: block;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 4.25rem;
  }

  &:after {
    content: '\201D';
    display: block;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 2.625rem;
  }

  font-weight: bold;
`;
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66817535/1952287) recommends double colons from [Can anyone tell me why before not working on styled components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66817477/can-anyone-tell-me-why-before-not-working-on-styled-components):

```
const Foo = styled.p`
  &::before {
    content: '\201C';
    display: block;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 4.25rem;
  }

  &::after {
    content: '\201D';
    display: block;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 2.625rem;
  }

  font-weight: bold;
`;
```

but I'm unable to render a `before` or `after`. Further research I've seen where content might be an issue but I'm referencing them correctly per [Double Quotation](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/punctuation/left-double-quotation-mark/) and a height or width should be declared and I've made sure to pass a `height` in `rem`.

Using Styled Components version `"^5.3.5"`, I've removed my cache, dumped the public directory and I've tested in Chrome and Firefox but I'm unable to render quotes.

### Research

- [Before and After pseudo classes used with styled-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871439/before-and-after-pseudo-classes-used-with-styled-components)
- [Using Styled Components and passing props to psedo element before not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70416587/using-styled-components-and-passing-props-to-psedo-element-before-not-working)
- [Can anyone tell me why before not working on styled components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66817477/can-anyone-tell-me-why-before-not-working-on-styled-components)
- [Why is :before pseudoelement rendered before content, not element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176267/why-is-before-pseudoelement-rendered-before-content-not-element)
- [Styled-components multiple Pseudo Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52802262/styled-components-multiple-pseudo-elements)

What am I doing wrong and how can I render pseudo elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardcoded approach from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74184472/1952287):

```
&:before {
    content: "“";
    display: block;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 4.25rem;
  }

  &:after {
    content: "”";
    display: block;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 2.625rem;
  }
```

works as a temporary solution but wasn't the desired course of action because I wanted to know why the code wouldn't be allowed.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74184983/1952287) suggesting

> You need to escape the quotes.

```
const Foo = styled.p`
    font-weight: bold;

    &::before {
        content: "\\201C\";
        display: block;
        font-size: 4rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        height: 4.25rem;
    }
    &::after {
        content: "\\201D\";
        display: block;
        font-size: 4rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        height: 2.625rem;
    }
`;
```

is wrong. The issue was escaping the backslash (`\`). If you escape the quotes then it errors out. As mentioned in other Q&As the preferred approach is to also use single quotes.

Solution to resolve the issue with the code was to terminate the backslash:

```
const Foo = styled.p`
    font-weight: bold;

    &::before {
        content: '\\201C';
        display: block;
        font-size: 4rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        height: 4.25rem;
    }
    &::after {
        content: '\\201D';
        display: block;
        font-size: 4rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        height: 2.625rem;
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDITED:**

@zharkov-ruslan is correct.  You need to escape the `\` in the content property.  The following works:

```
const Foo = styled.p`
    font-weight: bold;

    &::before {
        content: "\\201C";
        display: block;
        font-size: 4rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        height: 4.25rem;
    }
    &::after {
        content: "\\201D";
        display: block;
        font-size: 4rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        height: 2.625rem;
    }
`;
```

In addition to just inserting the actual character as a string, you can also use the CSS keywords `open-quote` and `close-quote`.

```
const Foo = styled.p`
    font-weight: bold;

    &::before {
        content: open-quote;
        display: block;
        font-size: 4rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        height: 4.25rem;
    }
    &::after {
        content: close-quote;
        display: block;
        font-size: 4rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        height: 2.625rem;
    }
`;
```

Comment: That is wrong though and errors out. The later solution is an interesting approach and I learned something new but if you go by the first approach of terminating the quotes it causes an error.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't get any errors when I escape the quotes and it renders the characters properly, so I'm going to leave this here for others.  Happy though that you have other options to solve the problem!

Comment: ah it looks like it might be an ESLint error, debugging now, but I was able to figure it out, I needed to terminate the backslash. Did upvote for the second half was unaware you could do that.

Comment: Cool, and yes, it does appear to be the \ that needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Probably something is wrong with your `content` property inside the pseudo elements, I changes values in that fields and styles worked fine with &:before, &:after.

```
const Foo = styled.p`
  &:before {
    content: "“";
    display: block;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 4.25rem;
  }

  &:after {
    content: "”";
    display: block;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 2.625rem;
  }

  font-weight: bold;
`;
```

Comment: I could see that approach to resolve the issue temporarily but shouldn't `content` allow the defined code?

Comment: It allows to use approach from @jme11 mentioned before with `\\201D`. For me it worked too. I checked it via CodeSandbox. Seems that using \\ works for styled-components, because with the plain CSS it works fine with your posted code: `\201D`. I think the trick is related to template literals in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this when I'm using pseudo elements:

- 'position: relative' on parent.
- 'position: absolute' on the child element.

Comment: I'm somewhat unsure how this answers the question?

Comment: This is my first answer to a stack overflow question, so I may not have done it perfectly. However, I looked at the question from my CSS perspective. Generally, when adding pseudo-elements it's good to use a CSS property called "position". You can set the position to a "relative" in the parent element and use the position "absolute" in the child element. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Comment: um I still dont know how that would resolve the issue to the question.